# Add a Swift Package to a workspace in a script

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package

I can create a new Swift Package in Xcode and able to add it in a workspace.
This can be done using Xcode -> File -> New Package, add the name and select the workspace in "Add to" and select the folder in "Group".
Then I can use this local package in another project within the same workspace.

Now I want to write a script that does the same thing.
I learn about

```
swift package init
```

but this only creates the package and not sure how to add this to the workspace.
Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new Swift Package, or make sure you have an existing package
  with a Package.swift file.
- Open your Xcode workspace (.xcworkspace)
  that you want to add the Swift Package to.
- Use the following script
  to add the Swift Package to the workspace:

#!/bin/bash

## Variables

WORKSPACE_PATH="YourWorkspace.xcworkspace"
PACKAGE_PATH="path/to/YourSwiftPackage"  # Replace with the actual path to your Swift Package

```
# Verify that the workspace file exists
if [ -f "$WORKSPACE_PATH" ]; then
    echo "Adding Swift Package to the workspace..."
else
    echo "Workspace file not found: $WORKSPACE_PATH"
    exit 1
fi

# Use `xcodebuild` to add the Swift Package to the workspace
xcodebuild -workspace "$WORKSPACE_PATH" -list

# Verify that the package path exists
if [ -d "$PACKAGE_PATH" ]; then
    echo "Package path found: $PACKAGE_PATH"
else
    echo "Package path not found: $PACKAGE_PATH"
    exit 1
fi

# Add the package to the workspace
xcodebuild -workspace "$WORKSPACE_PATH" -scheme "YourAppScheme" -package-id "com.yourpackageid" -package-path "$PACKAGE_PATH" -package-branch "main"
```